# Powershell equivalent of LINQ's Select command?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, powershell

I am trying to run the following Powershell script.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=vw,DC=local" | select-object name

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {gpupdate /target:Computer}
```

The issue is `$computers` is not a `string[]` like `-ComputerName` expects. It really is a Array of `ADComputer` with one paramter called name.

```
# Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=vw,DC=local" | select-object name | Format-Custom

class ADComputer
{
  name = PC1
}

class ADComputer
{
  name = PC2
}

class ADComputer
{
  name = PC3
}
```

What is the correct way to get a array of strings for the names? If I was in C# I know it would be

```
string[] computerNames = computers.Select(computer => computer.name).ToArray();
```

but I want to learn how to do it in Powershell correctly.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

or (probably the closest equivalent)

```
ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
```

Note that to force the result to be an array (e.g. if you want access to its `Count` property), you should surround the expression with `@()`. Otherwise the result might be an array *or* a single object.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was missing, I will accept the answer once it lets me.